# Share calendar with non iOS user

Tags: sharing, windows, android

How does one share their calendar with a non-Iphone/ios user? I've tried everything and it seems that all your downloads and accesses keep you chasing in circles.

Answer (score 6):

If you have an iPhone and you use the calendar on it then you can easily put it in Apple's cloud, iCloud, and from there it is easily shared.

First, on your phone go to "Settings" and select iCloud. Make sure Calendars is is flicked across to green and your Calendar is in the cloud.

Now in a web browser go to [iCloud.com](http://icloud.com/") and click on "Calendar". This will show you all the calendars you have in the cloud. See my example below :-

[image]

Now if you click on the pie slice to the right of the name it brings up a sharing dialog.

[image]

If the other person also has an iCloud account then you can share your calendar to them privately and allow them to edit it. Otherwise a public, read only share can be given to anyone who can read a calendar in CalDAV format. You can see the incredibly long address in the screen shot. It's so long it is best to email it to someone straight from the dialog. Click on the "Email Link..." link and you can be sure the right address is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Google Calendar is capable of integrating with the reading of the iCalendar CalDAV format if you create your iCloud calendar as a Public Calendar. Plus it will sync to the user's Android phone too.

1. You just go to http://www.google.com/calendar on a computer, login with your google account.
2. On the left side, click on the arrow to the right of "Other calendars", click on "Add by URL"
3. Paste in the public iCloud calendar URL into the window that comes up.
4. Then open your Android calendar app, and go into the app Settings and click on "Calendars". You will now see an new calendar by the name of your iCloud calendar.  Simply check the box, and you will start seeing the iCalendar from within your android calendar app.